# jQuery AJAX equivalent for REST call by curl

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, curl

I am able to consume a REST service with following command on command line.

**curl -v --user uname:pass -H "Accept: application/xml" http://xyz.abc.def**

What is the AJAX equivalent for the same? How to provide username:password in ajax call? My current function without uname:pwd is:

```js
function getData() {
  var name, code;
  var serviceURL = "http://xyz.abc.def";
  $.support.cors = true;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "xml",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: serviceURL,
    success: function(data) {
      $(data).find("VariableTree Variable").each(function() {
        code = $(this).find("Code").text();
        name = $(this).find("Name").text();

        $("#variable").append("<option data-value='" + code + "'>" + name + "</option>")
      });
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown);
    }
  });
}
```

PS: Service is secured by Spring Security

Comment: If the service is secured using sprint security are you using basic auth in the curl command because otherwise i don't see how the curl command is working.

Comment: You need to understand [Basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). That's the default auth mode type for cURL. Look the in the request headers of the cURL request. You will see `Authorization: Basic sdfdfkhdfkasdfhsdiu` That's the same header you need your request. `sdfdfkhdfkasdfhsdiu` is  a base64 encoding of `user:pass`

Comment: -user uname:pass does basic auth.

Comment: @peeskillet my curl command works, I need lessons on jquery.ajax.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that curl used basic auth by default in the documentation (quickly skimmed), below my answer uses ajax with basic auth.

Comment: Yeah and I'm explaining what happens in cURL, and what you need to add to your ajax request. The answer from @abc123 explains it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break down the curl command:

> curl -v --user uname:pass -H "Accept: application/xml" http://xyz.abc.def
>
> -v is for verbose, unneeded in ajax
>
> --user is the plain text user auth, but it is sent as basic auth
>
> -H "Accept: application/xml" is to add the header "Accept: application/xml

In jQuery ajax to replicate this we'll need to do a few things:

1. send the username and password, in a basic auth header
2. accept xml as the return datatype
3. send the ajax request as GET as this is standard for curl

```js
// this function takes a username and password
function make_base_auth(user, password) {
  var tok = user + ':' + pass;
  // Base64 encoding is what is used by basic auth let's encode our username:password
  var hash = Base64.encode(tok);
  // Let's return the auth header
  return "Basic " + hash;
}

// let's get the data
function getData() {
  var name, code;
  var serviceURL = "http://xyz.abc.def";
  // getting the auth header value
  var basicAuth = make_base_auth(uname, pass);
  $.support.cors = true;
  $.ajax({
    // using http get as the command type
    type: "GET",
    // accepting xml as the return type
    dataType: "xml",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: serviceURL,
    // setting the basic auth header
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", basicAuth);
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $(data).find("VariableTree Variable").each(function() {
        code = $(this).find("Code").text();
        name = $(this).find("Name").text();

        $("#variable").append("<option data-value='" + code + "'>" + name + "</option>")
      });
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(errorThrown);
    }
  });
}
```

***Please Note [MPO]:*** If the service accepts JSONP I would recommend that usage rather than CORS, however either will give the same final result.

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation. Do I need to include any specific library for Base64 encoding?

Comment: abc123- I am able to make this work. Thank u very much.

Answer (score 1):

---

Hi, if you want to override the htpasswd security, i think you just need to write your url like :

```
var serviceURL = "http://admin:pass@xyz.abc.def";
```

Comment: already tried this, doesn't work. Also service is secured by Spring security.